# How do I add a controller?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise version 15.6.4 and created an empty WebApi Core 2.0 project.

I added the .NET component and the web component in the installer.

Which component should I add?
Or maybe a template?
[image: Try to add controller]
[image]

**EDIT:**
I add new Project:

[image: first]

[image: Create WebApi]

[image: And after all]

Comment: For what? What do you want to get?

Comment: @Backs, i want to create Controller using menu.

Comment: @Backs, and as you can see, when i try to add item- i do not see Controller

Comment: Have you checked **General** or **Code** option provided by VS17, present on your left hand side

Comment: Anyways, Controller is "just another class" Nothing special about it just the fact that it inherits from `Controller` base class. You can do it yourself. Add new class and inherit from `Controller`. You can add another question as of why your version of `Visual Studio` doesn't have a `Controller` sub-context menu of the context menu `Add`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You cannot add a Controller from the menu because your project isn't a web project.**

The `Controller` option is only visible for ASP.NET Web Projects.
For what I can see in your question, your project is not a Web API project from visual studio template, you should have much more folders than what you have.

See here the difference in the menus between a console app and a ASP.NET app :

**Console :**
  [image: From a console app]

**ASP.NET**
  [image: Asp.NET Core]

[image: Add Controller]

The option `Add > Controller` is only visible when you right-click on the **Controller** folder !

If you want to add a new controller when the option is not visible, just create a new class & copy/paste the code here and rename the class with the name you want.

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ProjectName.Controllers
{
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically you just need your class to inherits from `Controller` class.

**EDIT** : I suggest you to recreate your project as a Web Project, the icon of the project should looks like this if it is a web project : 
[image: Web project icon] not like this : [image: C# project icon]

Comment: How he could possibly have a `Connected Services` item in the `Solution Explorer` in a console Application?

Comment: That's a solution on my computer and I do have `connected services` item in the console application, you can always connect your console application to Azure Could Storage. Well that's the connected service I have, and I can install more.

Comment: I don't think the first thing he did when created "a Console Project", is connecting to a service. Anyways, this is a problem from the OP as he didn't mention what project template he used

Comment: Hmm, I didn't talked about `Connected Services` anywhere in my answer so I don't really get what you mean.

Comment: @Mahmoud, i update post. I do not use Console Project. And i know how to create controller by code, but why i can do it fron right-vouse-click?

Comment: @AdmiralLand I've edited my answer with the reason why you can't add a controller from the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, VS has context menu for this:

[image]

Comment: I think the option `New From Template` is not from `Visual Studio` by default. It's from `ReSharper` Do you use `ReSharper`? Actually, in Visual Studio `15.6.4` I have an option to add Controller directly

Comment: @Mahmoud I have no option for "New from template", and don't recall one in older versions, either.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about, I don't have it too. Because I don't use `ReSharper`. @john

Comment: @Backs, and my problem is that i have not "New From Template" and option "Controller" too.

Comment: If you right click on the `Controller` folder -> `Add`. You should be able to see `Controller` option @AdmiralLand. Do you use `Community` or `Enterprise` version of `Visual Studio`?

Comment: @Mahmoud, i use Enterprise version. But at home at use Community version and Community version has Add->Controller.

Comment: No, even enterprise version have it.

Comment: @AdmiralLand I think there might be an issue with your Visual Studio installation. I suggest you re-install Visual Studio from the official link